# which one is correct, " building of houses means" or "building of houses mean"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I am trying to improve on my linguistic skills in English and struggling a lot. Yesterday, I wrote an essay, but I am confused about a sentence: 
"Building of houses means less number of open areas with trees."

I am wondering  if it should be means or mean. Does the verb(mean) refer to building or houses?

Comment: ***means*** is fine there.

Comment: "fewer numbers" - not "less number". https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/less-or-fewer

Comment: There is an implied "the": "The building of houses means..."  It refers to the general action of building houses rather than multiple instances of building individual houses.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct sentence:

> Building houses means fewer numbers of open areas with trees.

**Subject**: Building houses
**Verb**: means

Comment: @Catija: Thanks for the pointer! I didn't notice it as I just focused on the agreement between the subject and the verb.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "number" at all and, while it may not be strictly wrong, it's awkward. And I'd change other parts of the sentence too.  I would say:

> If more houses are built there will be fewer open areas with trees.

or

> Building more houses means fewer open areas with trees.